# Symfony 3 use of parameter

Tags: symfony

I am quite new to symfony...

And I have a (some) problem...

I have different configuration for dev and prod as almost everyone. I want to use a parameter defined in `config_dev.yml` and `config_prod.yml` as follow (different in the two files)

```
parameters:
    site_root: '/path/to/my/web/folder/root/'
```

I can re-use this value, `$this->getParameter('site_root'`), in a controller but I need to use it in classes in order to be able to save files, etc.
I can't find a way...

Thanks for help

Comment: Inject them in the classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I have used a relative link with `__DIR__.'/../../path/I/want/'` in place of going from the route. (In case it helps someone...)

Answer (score 3):

Yml service definition (services.yml):

```
services:
    my_class:
       class: Foo\Bar\MyClass
       arguments:
          - %site_root%
```

It's inject parameter site_root as argument to MyClass::__construct

Comment: Thanks. So I have to define it for all the classes ? There is not a more "elegant" way ?

Comment: Ah no, I have not well understood... In fact it will take the value from config and then use it for the different classes listed in services ?

Comment: Sorry... but how can I access to the argument from the constructor, I have tried different naming, but none worked.

Comment: protected $siteRoot;

public function __construct($siteRoot) 
{
     $this->siteRoot = $siteRoot;
}

And you can use $this->siteRoot in class methods.

Comment: Didn't know we can do like this. However it doesn't work as it says "Warning: Missing argument 1 for AppBundle\Shortcut\Shortcut::__construct()". inside the services.yml I have set     app.shortcut:
       class: AppBundle\Shortcut\Shortcut
       arguments:
          - %site_root%

Comment: How you use this class?

Comment: from a controller I will call this class to create a file after specific treatments

Comment: $this->get('app.shortcut')?

Comment: You're was register this class and now can use as service.

$shortcutInstanceFromDI = $this->get('app.shortcut');

It's work in controllers, also now you can inject this service in other services. Read more about Dependency Injection Container in Symfony

Answer (score 0):

As I can't manage to make Artur's solution to work (maybe I haven't got the knowledge yet), I pass the parameter to the constructor of the class... (Maybe it's what Federico meant by injecting in the classe).

It's not really "elegant", but it achieves what I need, waiting to have more knowledge...

Thanks